# Restkit: Coerced object mapping result containing 10 objects into singular result.

Tags: json, mapping, restkit

If I'm getting back an array of objects in JSON, and I've set a mapping for those objects, why does RestKit only return me one object instead of an array?

RestKit gives this output in the log: 
Coerced object mapping result containing 10 objects into singular result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the Method you invoke on the RKObjectMappingResult.

```
...
yourMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[YourExchangeObject class]];   
[yourMapping mapKeyPath:@"attribute" toAttribute:@"attribute"];  
...

RKObjectMappingProvider *provider = [RKObjectMappingProvider new]; 
[provider setMapping:yourMapping forKeyPath:@""]; 

RKObjectMapper *mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:provider];
RKObjectMappingResult *mappingResult = [mapper performMapping];
```

so now if you call

```
NSObject *object = [mappingResult asObject];
```

you'll get the "Coerced object mapping result containing ..." warning and only one result will be deliverd

call instead

```
NSArray *array = [mappingResult asCollection];
```

and it should work